# JWPlayer Chromecast in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am developing live video playing feature in React Native project.
I decided to use react-native-jw-media-player for that and it works well.
But the library has no chromecast feature.

If someone has any idea for that, let me know please.
I am appreciate can help me.

Thank you.